# Как сделать чтобы моя программа останавливалась при нажатии Escape, а при повторном нажатии продолжала работать

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура, key, keyboardhook

Хотел сделать паузу в своей небольшой игре, но столкнулся с проблемой, что все работает наоборот, да и метод у меня не особо хороший в плане кода, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы моя игра останавливалась при нажатии Escape, а при повторном нажатии продолжалась

```py
import os
import sys
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas, ALL, NW, Button
from keyboard import *
from time import *
import threading

class Cons:
    roadSpeed = 80

class Game(Canvas, Button):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(
            parent, width=1024, height=900, highlightthickness=0, background="black"
        )
        self.start()
        self.pack()
    def start(self):
        self.inGame = True
        self.score = 0
        self.barrierX = 128
        self.barrierY = -500
        self.loadImages()
        self.createObjects()
        self.locateBarrier()
        self.bind_all("<Key>", self.keyPressed)
        self.after(100, self.onTimer)

    def loadImages(self):
        self.icar = Image.open("ttt.png")
        self.car = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.icar)
        self.ienemy = Image.open("enemy.png")
        self.barrier = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.ienemy)
        self.iroad = Image.open("1396441575.png")
        self.road = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.iroad)

    def createObjects(self):
        self.create_image(512, 502, image=self.road, tag="road")
        self.create_image(128, 650, image=self.car, tag="car")
        self.create_text(
            30, 10, text="Счет: {0}".format(self.score),
            tag="score", fill="white"
        )

    def moveLeft(self):
        car = self.find_withtag("car")
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.bbox(car)
        if x1 - 256 > 2:
            self.move(car[0], -256, 0)

    def moveRight(self):
        car = self.find_withtag("car")
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.bbox(car)
        if x1 + 256 < 1022:
            self.move(car[0], 256, 0)

    def checkBarrierCollision(self):
        barrier = self.find_withtag("barrier")
        car = self.find_withtag("car")
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.bbox(car)
        overlap = self.find_overlapping(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        for i in overlap:
            for j in range(0, len(barrier)):
                if barrier[j] == i:
                    self.inGame = False

    def moveRoadAndBarrier(self):
        road = self.find_withtag("road")
        cnt = 0
        for i in range(len(road)):
            x, y = self.coords(road[i])
            if y < 450:
                cnt += 1
        if cnt == 0:
            self.create_image(512, -450, image=self.road, tag="road")
            self.tag_lower("road")
        barrier = self.find_withtag("barrier")
        cnt = 0
        x, y = self.coords(barrier[0])
        if y < 1024:
            cnt += 1
        if cnt == 0:
            self.locateBarrier()
        road = self.find_withtag("road")
        z = 0
        while z < len(road):
            self.move(road[z], 0, Cons.roadSpeed)
            z += 1
        z = 0
        while z < len(barrier):
            self.move(barrier[z], 0, Cons.roadSpeed)
            z += 1

    def locateBarrier(self):
        barrier = self.find_withtag("barrier")
        for i in range(0, len(barrier)):
            self.delete(barrier[i])
        self.score += 1
        r = random.randint(1, 3)
        for i in range(r):
            r1 = random.randint(1, 4)
            r2 = r1 - 1
            self.create_image(256 * r2 + 128, -20, image=self.barrier, tag="barrier")

    def keyPressed(self, e):
        car = self.find_withtag("car")
        x, y = self.coords(car)
        key = e.keysym
        leftKey = "Left"
        if key == leftKey and x >= 128:
            self.moveLeft()
        rightKey = "Right"
        if key == rightKey and x <= 896:
            self.moveRight()

    def onTimer(self):
        road = self.find_withtag("road")
        for i in range(len(road)):
            x, y = self.coords(road[i])
            if y == 1502:
                self.delete(road[i])
        self.drawScore()
        self.checkBarrierCollision()
        if self.inGame:
            self.moveRoadAndBarrier()
            self.after(100, self.onTimer)
        else:
            self.gameOver()

    def drawScore(self):
        score = self.find_withtag("score")
        self.itemconfigure(score, text="Счет: {0}".format(self.score))
    def gameOver(self):
        self.delete(ALL)
        self.create_text(self.winfo_width() / 2, self.winfo_height() / 2,
                         text="Игра окончена со счетом {0}".format(self.score), fill="blue")
class Car(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.master.title('ооаоаа')
        self.board = Game()
        self.pack()

root = Tk()
ooaoaa = Car()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Зависит от того, что такое «моя игра»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант через потоки:

```py
import keyboard
import time
import threading

stop = True # По умолчанию программа на паузе

def key_pause():
    keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', stopgame)
    keyboard.wait()

def stopgame():
    global stop
    if stop == False:
        stop = True
    else:
        stop = False

def my_pause():
    global stop
    while stop:
        time.sleep(1)

def main():
    print("Start")

    # обработка паузы
    my_pause()

    print("END")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    task1 = threading.Thread(target=key_pause, daemon=True)
    task1.start()
    main()
```

Из нюансов для наглядности программа стартует на паузе `esc` по сути меняет состояние переменной `stop`. А в местах где будет вызвана `my_pause()` будет проводится проверка на паузу.
Также данную логику можно реализовать через `threading.Event()`

```py
import keyboard
import threading
import time

# Обработка нажатия esc
# По нажатия будет вызвана функция stopgame
def key_pause():
    keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', stopgame)
    keyboard.wait()

# Функция stopgame просто меняет состояние event-та
def stopgame():
    if event.is_set():
        event.clear() # False
    else:
        event.set() # True

 # функция с которой запускается ваша программа
def main():
    # Какой-то ваш код
    print("Start")
    
    # обработка паузы
    # Вставьте этот код в программе где хотите чтобы
    # была проверка на паузе программа или нет.
    # если да то программа зависнет пока event не изменится
    event.wait()

    # Какой-то ваш код
    print("END")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event = threading.Event() # Создаем event
    
    # запускаем в отдельном потоке проверку надатия esc
    task1 = threading.Thread(target=key_pause, daemon=True) 
    task1.start()

    # начальная функция Вашей игры.
    main()
```

Ваш код:

```html
import os
import sys
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas, ALL, NW, Button
from time import *
import threading
from keyboard import *
import keyboard

class Cons:
    roadSpeed = 80

class Game(Canvas, Button):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(
            parent, width=1024, height=900, highlightthickness=0, background="black"
        )
        self.start()
        self.pack()
    def start(self):
        self.inGame = True
        self.score = 0
        self.barrierX = 128
        self.barrierY = -500
        self.loadImages()
        self.createObjects()
        self.locateBarrier()
        self.bind_all("<Key>", self.keyPressed)
        self.after(100, self.onTimer)

    def loadImages(self):
        self.icar = Image.open("ttt.png")
        self.car = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.icar)
        self.ienemy = Image.open("enemy.png")
        self.barrier = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.ienemy)
        self.iroad = Image.open("1396441575.png")
        self.road = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.iroad)

    def createObjects(self):
        self.create_image(512, 502, image=self.road, tag="road")
        self.create_image(128, 650, image=self.car, tag="car")
        self.create_text(
            30, 10, text="Счет: {0}".format(self.score),
            tag="score", fill="white"
        )

    def moveLeft(self):
        car = self.find_withtag("car")
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.bbox(car)
        if x1 - 256 > 2:
            self.move(car[0], -256, 0)

    def moveRight(self):
        car = self.find_withtag("car")
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.bbox(car)
        if x1 + 256 < 1022:
            self.move(car[0], 256, 0)

    def checkBarrierCollision(self):
        barrier = self.find_withtag("barrier")
        car = self.find_withtag("car")
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.bbox(car)
        overlap = self.find_overlapping(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        for i in overlap:
            for j in range(0, len(barrier)):
                if barrier[j] == i:
                    self.inGame = False

    def moveRoadAndBarrier(self):
        event.wait() # <<< Можно вызватиь тут
        road = self.find_withtag("road")
        cnt = 0
        for i in range(len(road)):
            x, y = self.coords(road[i])
            if y < 450:
                cnt += 1
        if cnt == 0:
            self.create_image(512, -450, image=self.road, tag="road")
            self.tag_lower("road")
        barrier = self.find_withtag("barrier")
        cnt = 0
        x, y = self.coords(barrier[0])
        if y < 1024:
            cnt += 1
        if cnt == 0:
            self.locateBarrier()
        road = self.find_withtag("road")
        z = 0
        while z < len(road):
            self.move(road[z], 0, Cons.roadSpeed)
            z += 1
        z = 0
        while z < len(barrier):
            self.move(barrier[z], 0, Cons.roadSpeed)
            z += 1

    def locateBarrier(self):
        barrier = self.find_withtag("barrier")
        for i in range(0, len(barrier)):
            self.delete(barrier[i])
        self.score += 1
        r = random.randint(1, 3)
        for i in range(r):
            r1 = random.randint(1, 4)
            r2 = r1 - 1
            self.create_image(256 * r2 + 128, -20, image=self.barrier, tag="barrier")

    def keyPressed(self, e):
        # event.wait() # <<< Можно вызватиь тут
        car = self.find_withtag("car")
        x, y = self.coords(car)
        key = e.keysym
        leftKey = "Left"
        if key == leftKey and x >= 128:
            self.moveLeft()
        rightKey = "Right"
        if key == rightKey and x <= 896:
            self.moveRight()

    def onTimer(self):
        road = self.find_withtag("road")
        for i in range(len(road)):
            x, y = self.coords(road[i])
            if y == 1502:
                self.delete(road[i])
        self.drawScore()
        self.checkBarrierCollision()
        if self.inGame:
            self.moveRoadAndBarrier()
            self.after(100, self.onTimer)
        else:
            self.gameOver()

    def drawScore(self):
        score = self.find_withtag("score")
        self.itemconfigure(score, text="Счет: {0}".format(self.score))
    def gameOver(self):
        self.delete(ALL)
        self.create_text(self.winfo_width() / 2, self.winfo_height() / 2,
                         text="Игра окончена со счетом {0}".format(self.score), fill="blue")
class Car(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.master.title('ооаоаа')
        self.board = Game()
        self.pack()

def key_pause():
    add_hotkey('esc', stopgame)
    wait()

def stopgame():
    if event.is_set():
        event.clear() # False
    else:
        event.set() # True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event = threading.Event() # Создаем event
    task1 = threading.Thread(target=key_pause, daemon=True) 
    task1.start()
    root = Tk()
    ooaoaa = Car()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: можете пожалуйста переписать это под мой код пожалуйста, я не очень понял

Comment: @dddfs8k7cvf Добавил подробное описание кода. Ну и если не получится то под спойлером готовый.

Answer (score 0):

используйте модуль keyboard

```py
import keyboard

stop = False
def stopgame():
    global stop
    if(stop == False):
        stop = True
        print("Пауза")
    else:
        stop = False
        print("Продолжаем")

keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', stopgame)
keyboard.wait()
```

Comment: Перед публикацией кода старайтесь проверять его на работоспособность.